# Transform .mat file to ROS2bag in matlab or python

Tags: python, matlab, ros, rosbag

I have a `.mat` matlab file containing multiple variables from a robot's movements. I want to convert these data into a `ros2bag`.

Is there a way to convert a `.mat` file to a `ros2bag`, with the rosbag folder containing the usual `.yaml` and `.db3` files?